# Merging two data frames in R on date/time with no ID

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr, timestamp

I have two data frames that I have tried joining together with dplyr's inner_join function.

`newdf <- inner_join(BM, HT, by = c("Person","DateBM"="DateHT","TimeBM"="TimeHT"))`

The problem I am running into is that both data frame instances I am intending to merge together have *slightly* different internal time stamps. For example, one may be 08:10:22 and the other would be 08:10:23. Both are occurring at the same time with two different data collecting technologies. Only ~20% of my data has the exact time stamps together that are matching up. The remaining 80% of data is off by 1-3 seconds.

Is there an addition to dplyr's function that would allow for the slight mismatch in timestamps? Will I need to manipulate my time column in both data frames to a numeric value (in seconds) and work from there? Something else I am not thinking of?

Comment: It seems to be that what you're asking is whether there's an automatic way for R to guess whether your data is correct or not. I would be surprised if there were a way to do this where you could be confident of the results. Depending on how sparse your data are (i.e. if they're collected every minute and not every second), you could reformat your time strings to be H:M instead of H:M:S and then join them

Comment: Somewhat. These data are collected 2-3 times every minute so H:M:S is required over H:M. I'm not sure if this is asking R to guess. I'm assuming there is a way to set the parameters to no more than an absolute value of 3 second difference to line up the two data frames. There may be some instances where there is no match, so those data can be excluded from the join.

Comment: But what if there are two rows in your data that are within the 3s threshold? How should R know/guess to which of these two rows the join with the other data frame should happen? Of course this depends on how your data collection works. If you know for a fact that no two observations are within a 3s range, then we can do some sort of matching I guess.

Comment: If the latter is true a very naive and ugly approach could be to create six columns in the first data frame, the first one being 3s earlier than your original time, the second one 2s earlier and so on.  And then you could kind of loop through these 6 columns and use them one after the other for the join with your second data set.

Comment: you could try lubridate::round_date(x,”5 seconds”) and round both sets of dates to nearest 5 seconds then try and join

Comment: @deschen It is certainly a possibility there are two rows in my data that is within the 3s threshold. I am fairly confident that there are less than 3-5% of my data that would be greater than that threshold. Most of the mismatched time stamps are 1-2 seconds off. There is typically around 8-12 seconds between each time stamp in both data frames.

Comment: @e.matt that worked for me, thank you!